# slik subversion hosting trac url for ide integration

Tags: intellij-idea, trac, mylyn

I'd like to integrate the Trac from a slik subversion hosting with Intellij. According to this [Tasks & Context Switching](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/tasks_and_context.html) this is rather easy but I'm unable to enter the URL for the "Server URL" field in the dialog.

I attached the mylyn tag because I think this issue is not strictly an intellij question because for mylyn you would have to provide a similar URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to enter the URL"?  Are you having trouble figuring out the URL?  Is the dialog not accepting input?  Does the dialog accept the input but return an error?

Comment: unable because I don't know what the actual URL is. I can access Trac from my browser but I can't use this URL in the IDE.

Comment: Trac is just a tool for viewing the code.  For Intellij, you need the URL for the real repository because the IDE will need to run Subversion commands against it.  How do you currently commit changes to this code base?  Whatever tool you use for committing should already know the repository URL.

Comment: IntelliJ has support for Trac as an issue tracker. You can change/modify tickets from within the IDE so you don't have to open your browser. E.g. you then can tell the IDE "I work on issue #123" and when you check in, the IDE asks if it should close issue 123

Comment: I see what you mean.  I was thinking you were wanting to use the IDE to do Subversion operations (update, commit, etc).  Usually, tools want the absolute base URL of the Trac installation.  For example, if clicking the "wiki" button on the top toolbar takes you to `http://foo.com/project/wiki`, the base URL would be `http://foo.com/project`.  Make sure that you supply valid login credentials or the IDE won't be able to access anything at all.